# wp_insert_post() Callback?

Tags: wp-insert-post, callbacks

After I added a post by [wp_insert_post();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post)

Any callback after I added ? I need permalink of added post.

I have idea only search by title and post-type (I use custom post-type in my case), But any better function ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $arg ); #returns post ID
$permalink = get_permalink( $post_id ); #returns the permalink
```

Codex:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

Answer (score 1):

Oh I found !

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post($arg); // return post ID
```